# App Engine preview does not work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets, jetty

Jetty opens up but it shows.

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

From my Eclipse console

> Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
>   INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
>   INFO: Successfully processed C:\Gowtham\eclipse\JS\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
>   WARNING: appengine-web.xml does not contain a  element. This will become required in a future release.
>   See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
>   You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
>   INFO: Successfully processed C:\Gowtham\eclipse\JS\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
>   WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@18706f6{/,C:\Gowtham\eclipse\JS\war}
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: /script/thejs.js
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1026)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1110)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:306)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:173)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:120)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:96)
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
>   INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
>   Apr 15, 2012 3:50:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
>   INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have an error in `web.xml` file. Dev server thinks `/script/thejs.js` is a servlet.

How did you map your servlets in `web.xml`? Please show us the contents of this file.